# Disable keyboard shortcuts for external keyboard

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to make a simple editor using `UITextview` on iPad. Everything was going fine until I tried my app on a device using an external keyboard. There are some keyboard shortcuts that interfere with my app: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>, <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>, and others.

I think I don't need some of these shortcuts, so I want to disable them. Can I do that? Can somebody tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Disabling keyboard when touched anywhere on view other than text field using UItTouch events

```
- (void) touchesBegan: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event {  
    if (myTextField) {  
        if ([myTextField canResignFirstResponder]) [myTextField resignFirstResponder];  
    }  
    [super touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];  
}
```

For more details please visit my blog:

http://aruntheiphonedeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/05/disabing-keyboard-using-uitouch-event.html